# Avatar & mentions, discordjs bots

Tags: discord.js

I can’t understand how to make it so that when I use this code, it will not only give me my avatar, but also other users when I mention them. I Need to do this with richembeds, as shown below. Help, pls.

```
} else if (command === 'avatar') {
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor('Akirabot. Your avatar.')
        .setColor(0x348fcd)
        .setTitle('')
        .addField(`${message.author.avatarURL}`, `Your avatar, click to url to open image with size 2048px.`, true)
        .setFooter('— Akirabot.')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setImage(`${message.author.avatarURL}`, true)
    message.channel.send({ embed });
```

Comment: If not difficult, write a sample code with richembeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;` It will get the mention incase if you mention someone or it will be the message author if there's no mention.

```
} else if (command === 'avatar') {
    let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor('Akirabot. Your avatar.')
        .setColor(0x348fcd)
        .setTitle('')
        .addField(`${user.avatarURL}`, `Your avatar, click to url to open image with size 2048px.`, true)
        .setFooter('— Akirabot.')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setImage(`${user.avatarURL}`, true)
    message.channel.send({ embed });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is Discord js v12 rn when I'm replying, u could use [ClientUser#displayAvatarURL](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL) for your bot
Ex : message.author.displayAvatarURL()